# find a match for a string in a vector of regular expressions

Tags: r

Suppose I have a character vector

```
vals <- c("hello","goodbye","junk")
```

and a vector of regex targets

```
targets <- c("(hello|goodbye)","^j","other")
```

(I'm willing to stipulate that each element in `vals` matches exactly one element in `targets`). Is there an existing, efficient/compact/vectorized way to find the index of the match of each element in `vals` in `targets`? (`match` doesn't work: it matches to a table of strings, not regexps.) Thus desired output is `c(1,1,2)` for this example. Base-R or tidyverse/`stringr` solutions welcome.

Comment: Is this too cute? `x <- outer(vals,targets,stringr::str_detect); col(x)[x]`? I feel like it might break in some cases.

Comment: I'm on my phone right now but I think stringi::stri_match_all_regex should be able to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach would be to set the names of the `list` with sequence and `stack` to a two column data.frame.  The `NULL` elements will be removed with `stack`.  Now, we extract the second column to get the `list` index

```
as.integer(stack(setNames(m, seq_along(m)))[,2])
#[1] 1 1 2
```

NOTE: Here `m` is the output of @BenBolker's `list` of index from `grep` output

---

Or using `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
crossing(targets, vals) %>%
    mutate(ind = group_indices(., targets)) %>%
    filter(str_detect(vals, targets)) %>%
    pull(ind)
#[1] 1 1 2
```

Comment: at first glance this is completely mystifying.  I'll think about it ...

Comment: @BenBolker  Yes, are you looking for a solution without `lapply`.

Comment: No, I was just confused -- thought this was supposed to be a complete solution and couldn't figure out where the matching was happening.

Answer (score 2):

The best way I can think of to do this: invert the matching, that is: iterate over the targets, then fill in the matches in a vector corresponding to the values.

```
## find positions in `vals` that match each target
m <- lapply(targets,grep,x=vals)
## set up response vector
res <- rep(NA,length(vals))
## fill in matching positions for each target
for (i in seq_along(m)) {
    res[m[[i]]] <- i
}
```

Comment: A similar chunk to this logic, just swapping out `grep` for `grepl` - `max.col(sapply(targets,grepl,x=vals), "first")` or even `max.col(vapply(targets, grepl, x=vals, FUN.VALUE=logical(length(vals))), "first")` since we know the output type.

Answer (score 0):

Using `str_detect` in `stringr`, loop each value over to find the target index.

```
library(stringr)

# Data
vals <- c("hello","goodbye","junk")
targets <- c("(hello|goodbye)","^j","other")

# create empty vector to assign matched value later
v  <- c()

for (i in 1:length(vals)){

  # value to be looked up against target
  stg_i <- vals[i]

  # min to get first matched target
  stg_v <- min(which(str_detect(stg_i, targets)))

  # update the value in vector with matched one
  v[i] <- stg_v

}

v
[1] 1 1 2
```